# How to use query params onload in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make it such that when my angularjs app loads, it reads the query parameters (`http://myurl/?params=Resource1,Resource2,Resource3`)of a url, then pulls all the JSON resources based on the query parameters (ex. Resource1, Resource2, Resource3). Once the 3 resources arrive, it updates one or multiple directives...i.e. "ListDirective1", "ListDirective2".

I have two questions:
1) Syntactically, how do I access the $locationProvider through the controller? Or is that not the appropriate place to get the query parameters and a service should be used instead?

2) Once I get all the resources and put them in an array as part of my main application controller $scope, what is the best way to make that information available to the ListDirective1?

Comment: I think you answered both your questions yourself. Anything that is not presentation declarative logic should not be in a controller. Use a service both for loading the resources and for making the information available.

Comment: Are services guaranteed to load after all directives and controllers have been initialized?

Comment: No. But that's why you have dynamic binding and promises.  So that your controller can use a service to get the data, wait for the promises to be fulfilled and then pass them onto the directive to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are looking for this

```
scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, current, prev) {...})
```

this will be called always when your routes changes

and to get the location provider in your controller, try this

```
yourApp.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){...})
```